# Failure of Questions to delete

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I have been deleting my answers for nearly a week to comply with the requirements needed to sever my connection to this stackexchange (at least that was the requirements I understood - delete as fully as you can and then request that your account be closed). I am in that process - scorn me a rage-quitter all you want. Today, my deletions have been restored and my reputation score amended. None of the answers had been accepted by the OP, so the moderators to the community should have no say in their deletion. I should have the right to delete and go, according to the guidelines, and wish to do so. To stay, I would have to concede defeat to a person, and the cronies of a person, who admittedly doesn't know the meaning of the word "Unsub".

What can be done about this? I wish to have my deletes to date replaced, and I will continue through the understood "slowing down process" you've placed of 5 per day. I am not going to be dissuaded; I am adamant.

I'm adding the support tag, only because I expect the reply to be a supportive action, not an amelioration, either for myself - or you.

Comment: Can you provide us examples of the questions in... question?

Comment: @wbogacz Why this sudden deletion? Can we know the reason? or any help from our side for any issues you faced.

Comment: Not sure about the 'culture' here but the content you contributed is no longer yours, but Stack Exchange's, under the cc-by-sa license. Your spree of deleting would be considered vandalism and would/should get *you* in trouble. Just saying. If you're frustrated, know that it happens to all of us, and the best solution is a (short) break and coming back when it's all fun to you again. Then again, seeing a contributor go is hurtful.

Answer (score 7):

The real question is why are you deleting your account and what can be done to resolve the issues that you've experienced leading up to this point? If this is something that we can help with you could always come and chat with us in public in [The Screening Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888/the-screening-room) or privately with a moderator.

If you do want to go ahead and delete your account (and we will be sad to see you go regardless of whether we've spoken in the past or not) then continue reading. For completeness, [the official Stack Exchange post for this can be found here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account).

I'm unsure who advised you that was the process to follow for deleting your account. Once you post content to Stack Exchange it is irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange so you shouldn't be deleting it unless it has quality or content problems.

To delete your account, you simply click on the "Contact Us" link at the bottom of any page on the network and request that your account is deleted. Note that **this is a permanent action that cannot be undone**. Once you have finished this step update your profile information to "Please Delete Me" and the account deletion will be processed in due course, resulting in all content against your account being anonymized and associated with an unclickable user (which in your instance on Movies & TV will say user304 as its name).

Alternatively you could bounty all of your internet points to me! :)

Comment: You're not a member for as long as me. Perhaps someone of long standing will remember. I've digested and considered that procedure for years, but it must have been reworded.

Comment: I'm not a member for as long as you as I've been through an account deletion already and was lucky enough that they were willing to undelete me, as such, my account creation date is 18 months after my account was actually created (as you can see by my first post being before my account creation date)

Answer (score 7):

It is sad to hear that you want to leave this site and I'd urge you to try and **bring whatever concerns you have to meta or chat** for them to possibly be resolved in order to not have a valuable contributor leave.

However, the way in which you chose to do so is indeed *not* the proper way to delete your account. Whoever told you so was mislead. **Deleting all your contributions before leaving is not the recommended way** and rage-quitting violates SE's primary rule to [be nice](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice). As *Flyk* explained in her answer, the proper way to delete your account would be to contact SE, as explained in the [help center](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account):

> If you *have* voted or posted, please contact the Stack Exchange Team:
>
> Visit the [**contact form**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/contact) and select 'I need to delete my user profile.' After you contact us, the team will reach out with further instructions.

As to deleting your own valuable contributions, this is not generally allowed on SE, as explained in the answers to [this related question](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1928/49). The fact that you don't consider your answer valuable anymore (or the asker by not accepting it) does *not* mean that the community doesn't either. Once you post something on SE, **it belongs to the community and you should not rob it of valuable contributions**. If, however, you are completely embarassed by a post of yours or want your username to disappear from it for whatever reasons, you can choose to [disassociate the post from your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-ccwiki) (which also robs you of some ways to maintain it, though, including accepting any possible answers).

Therefore, whatever your final decision about leaving or not leaving the site will be (preferably the latter, but that's up to you), I'd ask you to not delete any further valuable contributions of yours just in order to leave or to make a point. The moderators will continue to try and **reinstantiate any valuable posts you deleted**, not because we want to scorn or anger you, but because they are valuable contributions to the site that the community is not to be robbed of and doing so is against the rules and philosophy of SE.