# Removing my closed & locked identify-this- questions

Tags: support, user-accounts

After **identify-this-*** questions was discontinued, I have no interest in remaining on this site - partly because it was the type of questions I myself wanted answered, and partly because it tipped me onto lots of great movies and shows.

Before I leave, I would like to mark these question of mine for deletion - they're after all now considered off-topic.  Unfortunately - since they've been **closed** and **locked** - I don't have the **delete** question option available.

So could someone *please* just delete following questions (and their answers):

[Man and two children, cross-country car-drive, Italian, late 1980s, cinema-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73769/man-and-two-children-cross-country-car-drive-italian-late-1980s-cinema-movie)

[Young black girl shot at basketball-court, leg twitch](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/37438/young-black-girl-shot-at-basketball-court-leg-twitch)

[TV-series, 1980s, British, city, working-class-people, apartment-block, fall from window, children taken](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/47296/tv-series-1980s-british-city-working-class-people-apartment-block-fall-fro)

[TV news-station, San Diego, late 1970s, reporting news vs. selling sensation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/39365/tv-news-station-san-diego-late-1970s-reporting-news-vs-selling-sensation)

[Young American man studying in Paris meets young French couple](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/19612/young-american-man-studying-in-paris-meets-young-french-couple)

Yes, I know StackExchange technically "own" my questions and their answers, but since you obviously don't want this type of questions any longer, that ought to be a moot point...  And no, I rather *not* have them there for "historical" reasons, since they - tagged and explained as they are - now looks like they were "bad" and "illegal" questions from the beginning.

Comment: If your going to leave.. why do you care?

Comment: If it's concidered off-topic and will be sort-of hidden, why do you?  But to answer your question; because I'll still be using the rest of the site, and I don't want to be "remembered" in here as someone who asked a lot of bad/illegal questions - which it now looks like I did.  Besides, I usually ask for the deletion of any questions I've ask that gets tagged as "off-topic" or is downvoted below 0...  I would simply like to leave this place the way I found it - without any questions I've asked.

Comment: Remember, though, that we haven't stopped serving `plot-explanation` questions, so even according to your above expressed views there doesn't seem to be much of a reason to delete [this one](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81328/49) (*unless* this is more of a general attempt to rage-quit and make a fuss about it).

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Failure of Questions to delete](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1950/49)

Comment: If they *were* good questions, the votes should speak for themselves. I assumed you meant leave in the literal, so the questions *wouldn't* have your name on them. When you ask to disassociate yourself, your questions become attributed to the Community user.

Answer (score 5):

We had set a criteria for removing old Identification questions. Those which meet this criteria are kept but locked. They'll be kept locked to avoid editing and appearing in the question list.

From [this meta question about ID cleanup](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4138/27264),

> Thus we will be deleting all existing identification questions unless they meet all of the following criteria:
>
> - They have a score of +5 or more.
> - They have at least one answer with a score of +3 or more.

Since, your questions meet these criteria, therefore they are not deleted. They are apparently good questions. **However**, you can [ask for disassociation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732/162011), but these questions will not be deleted.

While talking about leaving, I will say the same as said by the author of the above post.

> **To those who appreciated identification questions and are sorry to see them go, we know you exist and we are sorry that this site didn't turn out to share your interest. Hopefully you still find this a worthwhile place and are willing to keep contributing to its content. We want your content and we know your film expertise goes beyond just recognizing a movie's story.**

Though, the identification questions are no longer on-topic, but it doesn't mean that you cannot stay here. There are lots of areas that this site covers and you can contribute to.